# Is there a way that I can show comment parameters for a method in the Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: c#

I have method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates Phrase SELECTED and either CATEGORY or CardChoice
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selected">True or False</param>
    public void UpdateSelected(bool selected)
    {
```

The Summary information appears but not the comment I have about the parameter.

Is there some way I can also show the parameter and it's comment "True or False"?

Comment: Triple comment above should work

Comment: As @RegisPortalez says, your syntax is correct, that should work. You can try saving the file, closing it, building the solution or restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you mean that VS should show parameters information also along with method information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the VS extension called [GhostDoc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeb.GhostDoc), it has more detailed xml comments than doing a triple slash. It fills out the description based on your method name, the param types and names, and the return type of your method.

Place your cursor anywhere on your method signature and hit `Ctrl-Shift-D` to include all the information you would need. You may need to change the description slightly but other than that, it is quite accurate.

You could also used the `cref` attribute in your `<param>` tags to reference the parameter type.